# Autosort uploads in galleries by filename

Tags: images, uploads, gallery, sort

A client of mine wishes to not have to sort images uploaded into a post gallery, but instead rely on its filename for sorting (e.g. "01_sample.jpg", "02_sample.jpg"). This would save a lot of time for the client, and I'm wondering if this is possible to achieve using WP 3.5+ and the recent changes to Add Media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you or the client add the gallery shortcode, you can add an "orderyby" option to specify the order of the images. Per the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) on the gallery shortcode:

```
[gallery ids="729,732,731,720" orderby="title"]
```

... will do what you're wanting.